# ACR build command not building Dockerfile

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-registry

I am trying to execute the following Azure CLI command targeting the Dockerfile in the root folder.

```
az acr build --registry <REGISTRY_NAME> --image myimage:latest .
```

And I get a `'.' doesn't exist` error.
Am I missing something basic here ?

Comment: hm, it looks like `--file Dockerfile` is implied. what shell are you using? this definitely works for me for both bash and powershell

Comment: Azure CLI in Windows commandline

Comment: try running the same in powershell, that should fix it, imo

Comment: getting the same error in PS too. strange

Comment: mhm, what ps version? that seems "highly unlikely". also, whats your cli version? can you try the same in shell.azure.com. that would work for sure

Comment: PS version 5.1.*. 
I have cloned repo locally so Cloudshell cannot be use as-is.

Comment: Updae: all good with Cloudshell. Local Powershell error still remains unsolved.

Comment: Do you in the directory that the Dockerfile and the application code files in?

Comment: @CharlesXu Yes I am in the same directory as the Dockerfile and app code base.

Comment: Then it was strange. It works fine on my side both in PowerShell and bash.

Comment: Can you list all the things in your current directory? And maybe you can use the absolute path instead of the ".".

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: It just worked for me when using CMD. But its still not working in powershell. Do we have to use a different command in powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause, but somehow PowerShell doesn't consider the current working directory. Try to use below command which use **$pwd** instead of **.**

```
az acr build --registry <REGISTRY_NAME> --image myimage:latest $pwd
```